# NoReverseMatch using reverse and url with args

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to use the `reverse` function in django with no luck. I already tried to change the args and use all combinations of long, int, string, unicode-string, etc, with the same error.

Help, please? Thanks.

Error I am getting:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /ajax/data-request
Exception Value: Reverse for 'views.watch' with arguments '(1, 1, 'aaa')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^options/', views.options, name='options'),
    url(r'^recuperar-contrasena/', views.recover_password, name='recover_password'),
    url(r'^ajax/login', views.login_ajax, name='login_ajax'),
    url(r'^ajax/data-request', views.data_request, name='data_request'),
    url(r'^peliculas-populares', views.movies_popular, name='movies_popular'),
    url(r'^peliculas-todas', views.movies_all, name='movies_all'),
    url(r'^watch/(?P<is_movie>\d+)-(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<name>.*)$', views.watch, name='watch')
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Reverse function:

```
'watch-url': reverse('views.watch', None, [(is_movie), (movie.id), (slugify(movie.title))])
```

`{% url %}` that works in my template:

```
{% url "watch" 1 movie.id movie.title|slugify %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `reverse()` call is incorrect, should be:

```
reverse('watch', None, [(is_movie), (movie.id), (slugify(movie.title))]
```

Comment: That one does not work, the one before the edit did work though. This one: `reverse('watch', None, [(is_movie), (movie.id), (slugify(movie.title))])`

Comment: @Pacha consider accepting the answer if it helped to solve the problem. Thanks.